# SelectionContext in iFrame - Permission denied to access property ‘getSelection’

Tags: javascript, iframe, firefox-addon, contextmenu, firefox-addon-sdk

On sites with iFrames I have difficulties retrieving the selected text if I take a detour via a context-menu content-script.

In main.js I define a context-menu-item with a `SelectionContext`, in its `onMessage`-method a `page-mod` `contentScriptFile` is informed. This script is then supposed to get the selection via `getSelection().toString()`.

But when being inside an iFrame this method either returns an empty string or getSelection is null. Trying to get the selection via parent window (`parent.getSelection()`) results in an error (probably due to Same-Origin-Policy):

console.error: Message: Error:
Permission denied to access property "getSelection"

Anyone any idea how to solve this issue? Thanx

Comment: Are you specify that your content scripts run on iframe? On the page mode I believe you have to specify: `attachTo: ["existing", "top", "frame"]`. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the `attachTo`-method was the solution for me - i needed:

```
attachTo: ['top']
```

Thanks to Christos Papoulas! (see comment under the question)